# VBA Run / do something when the file start up

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003

As an alternative to global variable, I am trying to read the last value I worked on at start up. I read this: [Excel VBA: Workbook_Open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13946645/excel-vba-workbook-open), and [this](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/auto-run-macros.htm).  and tried to implement my own. But it is not doing anything at the moment.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    MsgBox "Testing.."

End Sub
```

I noticed when I paste the following code into my project, it is in the `general`, instead of in the `worksheet`. I don't know if that's the problem, I already have a method that listen to changed in my `worksheet`.

Edit: This is the screen I am at right now...
[image]

Edit: I see what happened. ****I must open view > Project Exloper > This Workbook **** in order to click on `ThisWorkbook`. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you've probably put this code in the wrong module.

It needs to go in "ThisWorkbook" section of the project.

Just double click on "ThisWorkbook" in the Project explorer window in the VBA editor and paste your code into that.

Comment: I am sorry but I couldn't find "Thisworkbook" from the drop down menu, I see `General`, `Button2`, `Worksheet` only, I am uising Excel 2003 at work.

Comment: Make sure you have "ThisWorkbook" selected under "Microsoft Excel Objects" in the VBA Project tree. By the sounds of it, you have one of the worksheets selected.

Comment: Click on `View` then `Project Explorer` or hit `CTRL+R`. Then you should see the explorer and then `ThisWorkbook`

Comment: @Bathsheba lastly, do my `Global` variable has to be placed in `ThisWorkBook` too?

Comment: I think that would be a good idea as it helps with modularisation, but not completely necessary. Note though that if you click the 'reset' button in the VBA editor, then all global variables are set to zero / nothing.

Comment: @Bathsheba Global variable will not be accessible from the modules if its declared within this workbook source, globabl variables are only accessible if they are declared in the modules

Comment: Oh yes you can! And the notation is cute. E.g. put Public yogibear as String in "ThisWorkbook". You can refer to it in any module as ThisWorkbook.yogibear.